# Time conversion differs in IE and Chrome browser at this format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: jquery, json, datetime

I have the date format of YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS in json file.

For Example my date is "2014-01-31T00:00:00.000".when it parsed comes as like below.

In internetExplorer I have got like this,
Fri Jan 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

In Google Chrome I have got this,
Fri Jan 31 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Seems like chrome is handling it as the parsed Date is GMT+0 and not IE. This is probably a problem of using the Date API, check if you can force the TimeZone paremeter to have the good one or concat the GTM to the right value before parsing.

Comment: I've faced this problem too. If you have an option rather go for moment.js for cross browser standardization. Has helped me a lot!